# jQuery string casting as date and adding an hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, time, casting

I'm working with an API which returns dates in the following format:

> 2017-07-28T12:36:17Z

I'm used to working with unix timestamps. What I need to do ultimately is **add an hour to the time segment** in order to account for British Summer Time.

How can I cast this data as a date, add an hour and then output the time segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UTC formatted date, which includes a time string.

You can cast this as a JavaScript date using the `Date` constructor, e.g:

```
var testDate = new Date('2017-07-28T12:36:17Z');
console.log(testDate) // Fri Jul 28 2017 13:36:17 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Once it is a JS Date object, you can manipulate it as you need.

Comment: Here Date value will return according to your local time zone not in BST.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(new Date('2017-07-28T12:36:17Z').setUTCHours(1))
```

for British Summer Time (BST)
use `.setUTCHours(1)` . Check [setUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date()` function

```
var d = new Date('2017-07-28T12:36:17Z');
console.log(d);
d.setHours(d.getHours()+1);
console.log(d);
```